# laravel migration for change column type that used in a view

Tags: laravel, migration

I use laravel migartion to create some tables and then i create a migration for a view that use my tables.
now, i want to change type of column that used in this view (i create a new migration for it.).but, PostgreSQL does not let me to change column type because column is used in view. i want to know what is best way to manage this issue.

i tried to use migration that created view to drop then and recreate it after changing column type but there is problem because migrations doesn't have namespaces and i don't know is it good way for solving this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix my issue with following level:

1. add folder `common-queries` in `project/database/migrations/`
2. add `CommonQueries` namespace in `composer.json` with `project/database/migrations/common-queries` folder location.
3. add my view `create` and `drop` in a `class MyCurrentView` (for example).
4. use this class in old migration `up` and `down` function for creating and droping view
5. use this class in new migration and drop view before changing column type and create view after changing column type.

Answer (score 0):

First, my English is not good. What i understand is, you are creating a new migration with already existing table? If the table is already existed then you may try to change the column name using this

```
Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->string('name', 50)->change();
});
```

[Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/migrations#modifying-columns)

Comment: no, it's not my answer. i know how change column type i want a good way for solve column dependencies error before changing type.